# Robolectric 3.8 with MVP and mocking setupActivity()

Tags: android, tdd, mvp, robolectric, android-mvp

I use Android MVP architecture and I want to test my View. I have the following code in my project:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class MainActivityTest {


    @Test
    public void testDisplay() throws Exception {
        MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);

        final Menu menu = Shadows.shadowOf(activity).getOptionsMenu();

        assertEquals("Log", menu.findItem(R.id.menu_login).getTitle().toString());
    }

}
```

However, I get *ExceptionInIntializationError* for some 3rd party library throws it in the Activity's onResume() step which is invoked by Robolectric.

Moreover, in Activity's onResume() the Presenter's method is called which makes **a network request**.

My questions are:

1. How to mock 3rd party intialization step? I read about **Shadows**, but I don't know how to use them in this particular scenario. I should mock stuff during `setupActivity(...)` call.
2. How to mock the network call? In my MVP code, the presenter is created in onCreate() method. Should I switch to direct dependency injection pattern and rebuild the architecture? But this approach would conflict with `Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);` as I need some kind of **hook** to inject stuff in onCreate() or onResume() during Robolectric calls.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with the following solution. It is strange that I have never seen similar examples on their page or in articles. I have used **Mockito** along with **Robolectric**.

Firstly, I have added `setPresenter` method to Activity(MVP's View) to insert custom-mock Presenter into View

```
   @VisibleForTesting
    public void setPresenter(P presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }
```

In my code, Presenter is created **during** onCreate() method, so I have added **null-check** in order to inject Presenter **before** onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (presenter == null)
        presenter = providePresenter(App.appComponentFrom(this));
    presenter.create();
}
```

In Robolectric framework I have found `buildActivity()` method which just invokes Activity's constructor (no lifecycle methods!).

Then after this call I injected my mock-Presenter.

The last step is to call `activityController.setup().get()` as is does the same job as `setupActivity()`, which is calling lifecycle methods: `create(), resume()`

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Mock
    CheckoutContract.Presenter presenter;

    private ShadowActivity mainActivity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        ActivityController<MainActivity> activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
        activityController.get().setPresenter(presenter);
        mainActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activityController.setup().get());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkText() throws Exception {

        assertEquals(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getString(R.string.activityMain_title),
                ((Toolbar)checkoutActivity.findViewById(R.id.vToolbar)).getTitle());
    }

}
```

**Voila!** In my test I got Context Resources from `RuntimeEnvironment` and it have passed!